# Continuous Native Azure AD Sign-in

Tags: reactjs, azure, react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a React Native app that authenticates users by displaying a WebView with a `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?` url. Right now the user has to enter their password whenever the app is not in memory anymore (I think that's it) which is quite often. I was thinking of a way to implement browser-like automatic sign-in. There are packages that allow for storing web cookies etc.

My question is (and it might be totally off, let me know):

*What cookies should I store? Is it even cookies that are responsible for fore-mentioned type sign-in, if yes, can they be retrieved? Any and all suggestions are welcome*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What cookies should I store? 
>   If you are looking the way to persiste
>   nt User Login.

The JWT accesstoken that got from Azure AD and userId etc. should be stored.

> Is it even cookies that are responsible for fore-mentioned type sign-in, if yes, can they be retrieved?

You could get more information from [React Native: Persistent User Login](https://medium.com/@ntoscano/react-native-persistent-user-login-6a48ff380ab8).

The example is related to store the Facebook login information, but the principle should be the same.

You also could get the demo code from [github](https://github.com/ntoscano/ReactNativePersistentUserLogin/blob/master/persistentUserLogin.js).